# Creating a new list for each for loop

Tags: python

I wish to create a new list each time a for loop runs

```
#Reading user input e.g. 10
lists = int(raw_input("How many lists do you want? "))
for p in range(0,pooled):
    #Here I want to create 10 new empty lists: list1, list2, list3 ...
```

Is there any smart way of doing this?

Thanks,

Kasper

Comment: To all responders (so far at least): the OP did **not** ask to have a list of lists. He asked to have 10 separate lists! (Check my answer if this is not clear).

Comment: @mac: Yes, but this is **bad** practice.

Comment: @phantOm - Care to articulate? He might need to do this for whatever reason he did not explain in the question.

Comment: @mac The OP may not have specifically asked for a list of list, but I suspect that is essentially what s/he wants. There's no point making the problem more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @mac: "He might need to do this for whatever reason he did not explain in the question." This is the first problem we have here, he is asking for a solution to make his solution to this actual problem work! As for the bad practice: I cannot see any reason, why you would want to place those dynamically into the current namespace. Why would you want to do that, if accessing them again is only possible through the same ugly mechanisms how you got them there initially (as seen in your answer). You cannot reliable refer to them as list1, list2 etc, because you don't know, whether they're there.

Answer (score 8):

Use a list comprehension:

```
num_lists = int(raw_input("How many lists do you want? "))
lists = [[] for i in xrange(num_lists)]
```

Comment: Right, but this is **not** what the OP asked for. :(

Comment: @mac: The problem is, that the OP is having a problem with his solution to his problem, and is asking to solve the former, rather than asking how to solve his actual problem.

Comment: @mac: The OP might have literally asked for lists with names following a certain pattern, but since this requirement wasn't stressed so much, I don't think a -1 is in order. This is the Pythonic solution.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to create a list of lists:

```
   num_lists = int(raw_input("How many lists do you want? "))
   lists = []
   for p in range(num_lists):
        lists.append([])
```

Then you can access, for example, list 3 with `list[2]`, and the ith item of list 3 with `list[2][i]`.

Comment: This is not be the easiest way at all, but the -1 is a bit too harsh, IMHO.

Comment: @larsmans I meant that the easiest solution was to create a list of lists (which I think is true). A list comprehension is probably the easiest way to achieve that, though perhaps not the easiest to understand.

Comment: Yes, creating a list of lists is indeed the easiest and best solution. I do favor teaching new Python users about list comprehensions, since they exhibit a clean, expression-oriented style that is increasingly popular among Pythonistas.

Comment: @larsmans Yes, you're probably right. Personally, I love list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps in your situation you could use a defaultdict?

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> m=defaultdict(list)
>>> m
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
>>> for i in range(5):
...     len(m[i])
... 
0
0
0
0
0
>>> m
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: []})
```

Comment: Why -1? perfectly reasonable answer and `defaultdict` may turn out to be useful for the OP.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think using `defaultdict` is over-engineering for what seems to be a beginner's problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! My initial plan was to use individual list names, but I realized that a list of lists was enough for my purposes

Comment: @user838744: "enough" - it's not "enough" for you, it's what you virtually *always* want in such situations. The other isn't exactly manageable nor recommendable.

Answer (score 1):

To create our lists we generate names on the fly and assign them an empty list:

```
lists = int(input("How many lists do you want? "))
varname = 'list'
for i in range(lists):
    exec(f"{varname}{i} = []")
exec(f'print(f"list{lists-1} is", list{lists-1})')
# list9 is []
```